# Restart Blender each time a Python script is run

Tags: python

I am very new to Blender. I am an advanced Python user. I want to do with Blender something similar as with [OpenSCAD](https://openscad.org/), in case somebody here knows it. So basically I want to use Blender fully from Python scripts, the graphical interface only for visualizing the results. This means that each time I run my `main.py` I want Blender to be restarted and execute that script from scratch, without any memory from previous runs. Is this possible?

Of course one way to achieve this is to open a new project each time I run the script, reload the script and run it. But this is completely unpractical.

Up to now I have only found [this](https://youtu.be/rHzf3Dku_cE?t=482) which adds two lines

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
```

to select all objects and delete them. But there are many other things like materials, world settings, etc. etc. that would be nice to restart so I can be sure the script is doing all that I want.

Comment: You can open a new Blender and run your script with `blender -P script.py`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Have you tried invoking `bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings()` from your script?  That's pretty draconian, so maybe `bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(app_template="")` which restarts from your startup file.

Comment: @scurest thanks, that is very close to what I am looking for. Please promote your comment to answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219235/read-factory-settings-makes-all-other-operators-call-fail-in-a-python-script-ran